# WCF (SOAP):Protecting single operations with custom UserName validator - similar to what WcfRestContrib offers but for soap?

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security

I was hoping to be able to protect my WCF services on an operation level not service level.

Hence some methods are protected and others not. I know there is an attribute called `PrincipalPermission` but this works with Windows

I was hoping something existed for WCF Soap like it does for WCF Rest in this contrib project. WcfRestContrib

This extra project allows the use of a custom username and password validator and allow it only to protect certain methods by decorating the methods with an attribute

Is this possible with WCF (soap)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do operation level authorization checks with SOAP in WCF, but you'll need to do claims based authorization (as far as I know). That's what my team does for our product.

The hook point in WCF is to implement a custom ServiceAuthorizationManger

[ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.checkaccesscore.aspx)

[How to: Create a Custom Authorization Manager for a Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx)

and plug that into your service behaviour:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyServiceAuthorizationManager" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

When you implement your authorization manager, override CheckAccessCore, and then simply return true/false is they are authorized or not.